# Can I stop columns from breaking easylist items?

Tags: multicol, easylist

I have this code...

```
\documentclass{memoir}

\usepackage[ampersand]{easylist}
\usepackage{multicols}

\begin{document}

\begin{multicols}{2}
    \begin{easylist}[enumerate]
        & The alphabet
        & Declarative clauses
        && \textit{-r} alternation
        & Interrogative clauses
        && Partial (\textit{Liker du ... ?})
        && Polar (\textit{Hva heter du?})
        & Negation
    \end{easylist}
\end{multicols}

\end{document}
```

... which produces this output:

[image: Latex easylist/multicols output]

I know it's probably not optimal in this case, but I would like top-level items to not break across the column. In this case it would look something like this:

```
1. The alphabet                       4. Negation
2. Declarative clauses
    (a) -r alternation
3. Interrogative clauses
    (a) Partial (Liker du ... ?)
    (b) Polar (Hva heter du?)
```

I know it looks kinda weird in this case, but I think separating the subitems is worse, <s>and I'd prefer not to do it by hand.</s>

---

After making a few more of these, I realize that I am going to have to do it by hand where appropriate.

Comment: Could you provide a MWE, please ?

Comment: What information is missing?

Comment: \documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{easylist}

\begin{document}

Comment: Edited. Try that.

Comment: Lists are meant to allow all sorts of breaking across items, and there is no easy way to change this unless you're willing to change notation, or define your own list-like environments that do not allow that sort of breaking "in a nested level".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can force the "title" to stay by the list. I would also use \raggedcolumns to avoid that multicol tears the text to much apart:

```
\documentclass{memoir}

\usepackage[ampersand]{easylist}
\usepackage{multicol}

\makeatletter
\newcommand\mynobreakpar{\par\nobreak\@afterheading}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{multicols}{2}\raggedcolumns
    \begin{easylist}[enumerate]
        & The alphabet
        & Declarative clauses
        && \textit{-r} alternation
        & Interrogative clauses \mynobreakpar
        && Partial (\textit{Liker du ... ?})
        && Polar (\textit{Hva heter du?})
        & Negation 
    \end{easylist}
\end{multicols}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This doesn't seem to like being put in a `tcolorbox`. Any solution?

Comment: Not without a sensible minimal example. Imho this should go in a new question.

Comment: Okay, I'll ask it if I can't figure it out.

Comment: Hmm, the `tcolorbox` will accept a `\columnbreak` so I'll just stick to that.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how to do it with easylist but with the enumitem package :

```
\documentclass{memoir}

%\usepackage[ampersand]{easylist}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{multicol}

\begin{document}

\begin{multicols}{2}
%  \begin{easylist}[enumerate]
  \begin{itemize}
  \item The alphabet
  \item Declarative clauses
    \begin{itemize}[beginpenalty=1000]
    \item \textit{-r} alternation
    \end{itemize}
  \item Interrogative clauses
    \begin{itemize}[beginpenalty=1000]
    \item Partial (\textit{Liker du ... ?})
    \item Polar (\textit{Hva heter du?})
    \end{itemize}
  \item  Negation
  \end{itemize}
\end{multicols}

\end{document}
```

procudes :

[image]

I hope it could help you